# Debuging functions are disabling in IDEA

Tags: java, debugging, intellij-idea

Strange situation: suddenly I was unable to `Step Over` / `Step Into` while debuging Java code in IDEA 14. No effect when I press <kbd>F7</kbd> / <kbd>F8</kbd> - on panel buttons do not work.

Whats happened? Please help.

Here is my screenshot:

[image]

Comment: Can you share a screenshot?

Comment: http://i.stack.imgur.com/cHAt4.png

Answer (score 1):

You have some approaches there:

1. Update your IDEA, since version 14 was surely tested with an older JDK.
2. Remove your IDEA project configuration inside of that project and import it again.

I would suggest first one, since I had the same kind of problems using '15 after a OSX update. But the second one is simpler.

Comment: I suggest version 2016.3.

Comment: I tried one project with JDK7 and the second with JDK8 - the same problem. Could be the solution without changing the IDEA version?

Comment: Try to remove the project files from it and add it again to IDEA.

Comment: I tried to do this even created a new project with single source file but nothing happend

Comment: Well, after a lot of unsuccessfully attempts to repair debugging - finally installed IDEA 2016.2.4. - Surprisingly - It works!